# What does the FN key actually do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, keyboard

I like speedrunning, my PB is about 30 minutes, but my most reset-heavy condition is finding a nether fortress.

I've watched some tutorials about how to "Pie-Ray", which, requires getting up the pie chart in the <kbd>F3</kbd> debug screen, and seeing if there is a spawner in it, then going to the next chunk to see if it's that direction.

But, something about my computer really hinders the speed of that. If I press <kbd>F3</kbd>, alone, my Windows would just up the sound by a bit, if I press <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd>, it will show the debug, but if I I want to close it immediately by doing the same <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd>, it will up the sound.

Why is it this? What I'm really after is what does the <kbd>fn</kbd> key do anyway? Does it enables the other function of the <kbd>F3</kbd>, for a brief period of time? Or is it a toggle switch? I would really want to know the answer. Thank you in advance for all help :)

Comment: I actually run into this issue with turning my volume up and down at work ***a lot*** so I can see how it would be incredibly annoying to a speed runner. Thank you for asking because it made me curious enough to finally search for an answer lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a hold functionality:

> On keyboards with an Fn key, hold down Fn and press the key to use the alternate commands.

---

There are two possible explanations for what you're experiencing:

- You're releasing <kbd>FN</kbd> before pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>.

  - *Plausible during speed runs.*
- You're locking the <kbd>FN</kbd> key accidentally.

There is some [official documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-do-i-use-the-fn-key-f-lock-key-alternate-command-keys-fccfaf23-38f0-88a8-9b44-a18f24523b79) on the latter case for [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) computers:

> If your keyboard has an F Lock key, press it to toggle between the standard commands and alternate commands.
>
> - When the F Lock light is Off, alternate functions work (Help, Undo, and so on).
> - When the F Lock light is On, standard functions work (F1, F2, and so on).

If you have an all-in-one keyboard, the F lock works slightly different:

> To enable FN Lock on the All in One Media Keyboard, press the FN key, and the Caps Lock key at the same time. To disable FN Lock, press the FN key, and the Caps Lock key at the same time again.

Comment: Thank you! I think I've got it <3

Answer (score 1):

A laptop's <kbd>Fn</kbd> key (Function Key) is to give the buttons extra functions using the same keys. There are many different flavors for this, so unfortunately neither the placement nor icons are standardized.

In this screen shot, you will see a padlock with <kbd>Fn</kbd> inside, and that's a typical "Function Lock", locking the buttons to work as the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys, or the media keys:

[image]

Here you see the keys with the Media functions as the large icon, and the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys as the alternate options. Function Lock is still via the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key though:

[image]

The On Screen Keyboard on Windows 10 may have the Function Lock on the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key:

[image]

Some keyboards even have a dedicated button just for "Function Lock"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Taco's answer already covers how to fix your problem, but let me explain why it works that way.

Most keyboards have different characters or functions merged into a single key. For example, you can type both `a` or `A` using the same <kbd>A</kbd> key, depending if you combine that key with <kbd>Caps</kbd> or not. Other keys might have even more characters mapped to them, and you access them with <kbd>Control</kbd> or with <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd>, for example you get the euro sign `€` with <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.

Now lets move to the function keys. Historically, keyboards had a few function keys, such as <kbd>Escape</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Screen capture</kbd>, plus 12 multipurpose function keys, from <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd>. Each program could assign those keys a meaning, for example, <kbd>F1</kbd> usually opens the help, or in Minecraft, <kbd>F3</kbd> shows the debug info.

Then computers got better. Suddenly we had music, and CD players, and video! So they added a bunch of multimedia keys: <kbd>Volume up</kbd>, <kbd>Pause</kbd>, <kbd>Fast forward</kbd>, etc.

And then, we got laptops (and compact desktop keyboards), where space is limited, so what they did is combine together the 12 original function keys, and the multimedia keys. And they added the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to let you choose.

So when you press <kbd>F3</kbd>, you are not really using the `F3` *function*, you are instead using the primary function of that key, which in your computer is `Volume up`. In order to access the secondary function, you need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>, as you  already noticed.

Many keyboards have the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and the secondary functions in a different color, to let you know that those go together.

Also, depending on your laptop or your keyboard, it might be possible to switch the order, so that <kbd>F3</kbd> is indeed `F3`, and you would need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to turn up the sound. You can do that by using the "Fn lock" option explained in Taco's answer, or by changing some parameters in the BIOS/UEFI settings.